# liquid inside complex shape?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I am working on this complex object. I want water to flow inside it, but, the liquid keeps escaping everywhere.

[image: photo] [image: photo1]

Comment: hey, you should post your blend file so that we can look at your settings.

Comment: and how can i do that here ,sorry first time using this site .

Comment: here on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The first problem I see is that you're using a Curve object, and fluid sims can only interact with Mesh objects. So first create a Mesh version of that [Alt C]. Next, you'll want to pay attention to your mesh density and the real-world scale of your fluid sim. And make sure your face normals are pointing toward the fluid source - you'll probably need to flip them for that object, or Solidify.